# Did Google Chrome change how audio works? Audio code no longer working

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, audio

I've been using this audio that minimizes the overall appearance to just a small animated group of bars that you could play the audio just by clicking it. However; changes in Google Chrome no longer allows it to work as it once did.
I'm more than positive this is not me, as I've tested this with multiple computers with the same result.
The audio player is still technically "there" as you can just right-click it and open the audio link there. But not from the code itself.

This is what I'm using:

```
<style type="text/css">

#musiclocation{

 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 3.4em;
}

#musicgif {
background-image: url('http://puu.sh/qRJSu/873880d3c5.gif');
}

audio{
opacity: 0;
width: 2.8em;
}
</style>



<div id="musiclocation">
<div id="musicgif">
<audio controls type="audio/mp3" src="http://puu.sh/qRJ4f/abeebed630.mp3"></audio>
</div> 
</div>
```

Is there any workaround to this? Or better yet, a small little change to keep it similar to the code that I already have; The small blue bars on the bottom right of the page. It's driving me crazy that I can't figure this out

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what do you need , but I change the style to make it appear top-left and it appear normally ; you will need a javascript to make the file playable when you press the background image 
[image]